# Изменение разрешения изображения с помощь PHP

Tags: php, изображения

**Вопрос:**

Есть файл `generator.php` который создает одну фотографию из 3-х. Какой код туда ставить чтобы он при генерации выводил изображения разрешением 50x50px? Я в этом деле новичек пробовал несколько раз с разными кодами, но всё безрезультатно.

**generator.php**

```php
<?php
$background = imagecreatefrompng('./flat_background/red.png');
$shadow = imagecreatefrompng('./shadow/shadow_1.png');
$icons = imagecreatefrompng('./icon/list.png');

imagealphablending($background, 1);
imagealphablending($shadow, 1);
imagealphablending($icons, 1);

imagecopy($background, $icons, 0,0,0,0,100,100);
imagecopy($shadow, $background, 0,0,0,0,100,100);

header("Content-type: image/PNG");
imagePNG($background);
?>
```

**Цель:**

Нужно чтобы данный скрипт вывел изображение с измененным разрешением изображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте готовое решение http://image.intervention.io/
На главной пример ресайза картинок